# How to fix "missing return statement" in a for loop when trying to return individual elements in an array?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, compiler-errors

My assignment requires me to create an accessor to get individual elements of an array. I am using a getter for this and looping through the array with a for loop. I assume it is supposed to return me the textbooks in the array as I loop through this array.

When I compile, I get "missing return statement". I understand that this is because actually my return is inside the loop, but do not see how I can fix this.

BookCount is a number of books which has been earlier created to set the size of the array. arrayofBooks is the actual array where I will be storing the books. What am I doing wrong?

```
public String getBooks() {
    for(int i=0; i<bookCount;i++) {
        return this.arrayOfBooks[i]; 
   }
}
```

I expect the output to return me individual elements of the array.

Comment: It isn't missing from the for loop. It is missing *after* it, as the prior return only occurs if `bookCount > 0`. But your code doesn't make any sense anyway. The method should take an index parameter and you just return the element at that index. No loop required at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` causes the method to exit. The `for` loop would always exit the method on the first iteration. You need to be clear which `String` you are intending to return.

The compilation error occurs because the loop could be executed zero times. This could happen if `bookCount` was `0` or less. (The exact details are long, tedious and contained in the Java Language Specification under "reachability".) If the loop does not execute, then there is no `return` to execute and the value the function should return remains unspecified, which is an error. Also the `i++` can never be executed.